# remove form validation errors with a page refresh

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, validation

I have a page that takes form input, it is written using HTML and PHP(codeignter framework), the issue I am facing is when there is a form validation error, the page refresh is not reloading the page like brand new, I mean its not clearing the input from fields and the error message still coming up on page refresh and even after I correct the input and hit submit, when I click browser back button the it is still loading the page with validation error..
Any idea why it happens or how to resolve it. I just need the page to reload when I refresh it.

Here is my view (view1.php)

```html
<html>
<?php
    echo validation_errors();
    form_open('search_controller/search_fn');
    form_input('input1', set_value('input1'));  
    form_input('input2', set_value('input2'));
    form_input('input3', set_value('input3'));
    form_submit('submit', 'Submit');
?>
</html>
Controller Functions

function index() {
    $this->load->view('view1');
}

function search_fn {
    if($this->input->post('submit') {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('input1', 'XXXX',      
                                'trim|some_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('input2', 'XXXX', 
                                'trim|some_validation');      
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('input3', 'XXXX',
                         'trim|some_validation');

        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            //when validation fails
            $this->load->view('view1');
        } else {
            //when all input is validated sucessfully
           do some processlisng,
           //load some other view
           $this->load->view('view2');
        }
    } else {
        //When page is refreshed, this is supposed to redirect
        redirect('search_controller/index');
    }       
}
```

when the input validation fails, the url comes back as     www.something.com/search/search_fn and when I refresh, it basically loading the same page with same error message. I, somehow, need to reset 
the $this->input->post('search'), so that it will be true only when the search button is clicked.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems you have run into?

Comment: It's practically impossible to help you without you posting an example of the code you are having issues with.

Comment: Keep in mind, IE and other browsers save state (really annoying) and will keep data in the form even after page refresh. Don't know if that has anything to do with your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using CodeIgniter's `redirect()` function after processing form? you should always do that

I mean after you are done handling submitted data, instead of return TRUE or simply closing function, to a simple `redirect('CONTROLLER_NAME');` even if you want them to be on the same page

As for the fields, i would suggest using autocomplete="off" in your inputs `(if you are not using an <input type="text"> above an <input type="password"> because Chrome and next version of Firefox will ignore automplete="off" in that situation)`

Comment: If I add the redirect the page is being redirected to the new url I gave in redirect..I have updated my question to make it more clear.

Comment: @PREDDY I mean use redirect when form is submitted, not when the page is refreshed! for example change `$this->load->view('view2');` with `redirect('CONTROLLER_NAME')` and if you need to show any message after redirect use Codeigniter `flash data` , also change your inputs with `form_input('input1', set_value('input1'), 'autocomplete="off"');`

Comment: Thanks again Ara. The "view2" is supposed to be loaded with 1000's results fetched from database, so I could not use flash data to pass output to view. Also I am trying to use 'autocomplete="off"', but for some reason it is not working for input type="text" fields..Any idea on that?